# Android Kernel build job gets killed

Tags: android, kernel

I need to build some Android Kernels and set up a VM as Google tells me. I used Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 10.04 because the repo script depends now on newer git Versions and it seems that Google will use 12.04 in the futur too.

But all the time, while compilation i get an Error:

```
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclangARCMigrate_intermediates/TransBlockObjCVariable.o] Killed
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclangARCMigrate_intermediates/TransAutoreleasePool.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclangARCMigrate_intermediates/TransEmptyStatementsAndDealloc.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libclangARCMigrate_intermediates/TransformActions.o] Killed
```

no previous Error line, everythings fine but then something gets killed and the whole build process dies.

If i restart the build, it continues as usual until it dies again...

whats wrong here? How can i check why the job gets killed?

additional information: It does not depend on the `-j4` option. make kills the jobs even when i use `-j1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a RAM depended problem. we set up a new build server with alot of swap space and it works now